# MySQLのマルチカラムインデックスの部分一致が効くかどうか

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `tenant_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `email_idx` (`email_address` ASC))
```

上記テーブルの場合に、以下の検索をかけた場合インデックスは聴きますか効きますか？

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address = ? AND tenant_id = ?
```

インデックスとは完全一致していないですが、`email_address`を一つ目に指定することで、`email_idx`のインデックスが効いて、その結果の中から、`tenant_id`が一致するものを取ってくるという認識が正しいかを確認したいです。

Comment: 質問の例だとインデックス`email_idx`に完全一致した検索条件に見えますが、誤記でしょうか?

Comment: 回答ではないのでコメントしますが、多くの場合、`tenant_id`と`email_address`でUNIQUE KEY制約かけると思うので、問題にはならない気がしますね

Answer (score 2):

効きます。
試しにEXPLAINをつけてSELECT文を実行していみると、実際にemail_idxが使用されているのが分かると思います。

MySQL 5.6 - マルチカラムインデックス
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/multiple-column-indexes.html